# How can i get Bootstrap datatable to work with javascript automatic refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using using a script to call a html table that refreshes every 5 seconds.
The following successfully refreshes my HTML table every 5 seconds and loads the table from table.html on the index.html page:

**table.html**

```
<table><tr><td>TEST</td></tr></table>
```

**index.html**

```
    <html>
<body>
    <div id="tableHolder"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('table.html', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
    </html>
```

I am trying to implement the following, with a bootstrap datatable, my bootstrap datatable works when the table is included in the index.html page, however when i add the refresh script and place the table inside table.html the table fails to load and produces no console errors:

**table.html:**

```
<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">

                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Position</th>
                                                    <th>Office</th>
                                                    <th>Age</th>
                                                    <th>Start date</th>
                                                    <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                                    <td>System Architect</td>
                                                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                                    <td>61</td>
                                                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                    <td class="text-right">
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-info like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-warning edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-danger remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
</table>
```

**index.html:**

(Large HTML output removed)

```
<body>
                                    <div class="fresh-datatables">


                                    </div>
</body>
<footer>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#fresh-datatables').load('table.html', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatables').DataTable({
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
            responsive: true,
            language: {
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
            }

        });


        var table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

        // Edit record
        table.on('click', '.edit', function() {
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            if ($tr.hasClass('child')) {
                $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
            }

            var data = table.row($tr).data();
            alert('You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.');
        });

        // Delete a record
        table.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            table.row($tr).remove().draw();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //Like record
        table.on('click', '.like', function() {
            alert('You clicked on Like button');
        });
    });
</script>
</footer>
</html>
```

When i remove the refresh script, and insert the table between:

```
<div class="fresh-datatables">


                                </div>
```

It works, so i can't figure out why it will not work.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Try `destroy`-ing the table first then initialize again.